# CGI login script that redirects to another page

Tags: cgi

I am building a website that users would need to log in to. When the user hits the submit button, I want a CGI script to authenticate the users information, and if it is good, redirect them to another page I have set up. If not, display error. I am having trouble figuring this out. If anyone could throw some help my way I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use CGI for the website, in the first place?

Comment: It is what I am required to do at this point in the program.

Comment: Well, okay. I assume you know the pros and cons of this technology. It has its uses, but is often chosen when other, more convenient and modern techs can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

As you said nothing about the server-side language of your choice, I'm assuming you have no problem with that.

[CGI Programming on the World Wide Web](http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/) is a nice, if old, book on the subject. Please refer to it.

- Make the form send a `POST` request to the server (beware, the password is going to be sent unencrypted).
- For getting the the username and password supplied, use [form input](http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch02_03.html).
- After checking the password, [redirect](http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch03_05.html) the user with `303 See Other` either to the target page, or to the error page.

I guess you have certain reasons to use CGI, but honestly, if you need anything more sleek and polished, switch to any web framework of your choice.